# JS Keydown/Keyup with Modifier

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm using this (http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/) library to check keypress on my website.

I've made that code to switch a div's content whether the key is pressed or not. This script works.

```
shortcut.add("G",function() {

  document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML = '123';


},{
 'type':'keydown',
 'propagate':true,
 'target':document
});


shortcut.add("G",function() {

  document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML = '456';


},{
 'type':'keyup',
 'propagate':true,
 'target':document
});
```

Now when I want to check modifier keypress (For example <kbd>Meta</kbd> (=Command on Mac) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>), it doesn't work:

```
shortcut.add("Meta",function() {

  document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML = '123';


},{
 'type':'keydown',
 'propagate':true,
 'target':document
});


shortcut.add("Meta",function() {

  document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML = '456';


},{
 'type':'keyup',
 'propagate':true,
 'target':document
});
```

Is this a limitation of the library or am I doing something wrong?
If it's because of the library, can somebody please show me what to add in the script?

Comment: From [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html): *Alt, Cmd, Ctrl and Shift cannot be detected on Mac, except in Opera. However, you can always use the altKey, ctrlKey, and shiftKey properties.*

Comment: So absolutely no chance to get this working? Thanks for the hint btw.

Comment: @user555150: Honestly, I never tried so I cannot answer this question. But it seems not to be possible. You can only check this in combination with other keys.

Comment: So I can make the div switching with combination Meta-B for example?

Comment: EDIT: I've tried it with shortcut.add("Meta+B"... and it didn't work. It would be cool though if there is another possibility to do this...